# What are the advantages of specifying the parameter type and return type of a method?

Tags: python

I have just recenlty learned that you can specify the parameter and return type of a function in Python, something like this:

```py
def myDef(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a+b
```

Does this have any advantages considering speed or are there any other reasons why this could be useful?

Comment: Your IDE or other tools can better understand your code to find problems and make helpful suggestions.

Comment: The type hints are removed by the interpreter. The actual bytecode which runs is unchanged.

Comment: “Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live”

Comment: You can use `Mypy` to see how the syntax of your code is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the pros [***Type Hints***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) of are:

1. Type hints **help catch certain errors**.
2. Type hints **help document your code**. (you can also use
   docstrings if you want to document the expected types of a
   function’s arguments, but can’t be easily used for
   automatic checks)
3. Type hints **improve IDEs and linters**. They make it much easier to
   statically reason about your code.

*Type hints help you build and maintain a cleaner architecture. The
act of writing type hints forces you to think about the types in
your program. While the dynamic nature of Python is one of its great
assets, being conscious about relying on duck typing, overloaded
methods, or multiple return types is a good thing.*

It is definitely an avoidable practice as: it takes time and effort, work best in modern Pythons and it gives you a slight penalty in start-up time.